# how to get email from Facebook sdk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working on android Login with Facebook After login i want to save the data from Facebook i want to save the following data from Facebook

1. First Name
2. Middle Name
3. Last Name
4. User id
5. profile picture
6. Email
7. Profile Name

I tried some code which following

```
loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                String userid = profile.getId();
                String userfirstname = profile.getFirstName();
                String middlename = profile.getMiddleName();
                String userlastname = profile.getLastName();
                Uri userimage = profile.getProfilePictureUri(30, 40);
                String name = profile.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //info = ("Login attempt canceled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                // info = ("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
```

From above code i successfully get other all but can't get email.

**What i want**

1. I want to get user email
2. I want to create a new json array for **HTTP CALL** to save the above data from user account.

Comment: i think your question is not related to conent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try This It's Work For me**

```
 login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                RequestData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });




private void RequestData() {

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            final JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();



            try {
                if(json != null){
                    text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                    /*details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                    profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));*/

                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("name"));
                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("email"));
                    Log.e(TAG, json.getString("id"));
                    //web.loadData(text, "text/html", "UTF-8");

                }







            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

//Get Profile Picture from id

```
 public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID){
    try {
        URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large");
        Log.e(TAG,imageURL.toString());
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: i can't use this i'm to beginner in android please edit my code

Comment: read about "declarative fields" in the facebook docs, that is exactly what he added in the code. make sure you understand what is happening and it will be easy for you to edit your code.