# Android save Shared preference and get email of user facebook login sdk 4

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

i am building an app where users first login via facebook then it goes to another map activity.whenever i restart my app it shows logout button not login or just go to another activity plus i want to save email of my clients. here is my code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {





private TextView info;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
SharedPreferences sp;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = sp.getString("access_token",null);
    long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires",0);
    if (access_token != null){

    }




    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            Log.d("LOGIN_SUCCESS", "Success");
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //<- IMPORTANT
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();//<- IMPORTANT

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText("Login attempt Canceled");


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            info.setText("Login attempt failed");

        }
    });
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            // Set the access token using   `q
            // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
        }
    };

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




}




public void imageView (View v) {

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loofreLogo);
    if (img != null) {
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.loofre.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
public void InsOnclick(View args0) {
    if (args0.getId()==R.id.Bins){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,instructionSlide.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public void AboutUs (View args1){
    if (args1.getId()==R.id.Babout){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did you tried using shared preferences to save data?

Comment: @BhaveshMisri sir i dont know how to do that ... tried few tutorial from youtube and stackoverflow but unable to understand it ... So i need to create another activity ? for login i only this activity

Answer (score 0):

To save data in shared preferences, this is what you do:

```
SharedPreferences preferencesPut = getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("nameKEY", "name");
        editor.putString("emailKEY", "email");
        editor.putBoolean("done", true);
        editor.commit();
```

this will save your name and email. The string "KEY" is a specific key which specifies which value of shared preference you want to know. Then to fetch data back from shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences preferencesGet = getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = preferencesGet.getString("nameKEY", "default");
String email = preferencesGet.getString("emailKEY", "default");
```

you will get the name and email in strings 'name' and 'email'. You will get value "default" if you are not able to save data in shared preferences or couldn't fetch it.

Comment: unable to implement this in my project help please

Comment: are you able to fetch name and email? if yes, put them in the first part of code. Instead of "name" and "email" put in your name and email.

Comment: @Bhaesh Misri followed this answer - is this will gonna work out ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183258/how-to-get-email-from-facebook-sdk-4-0

Comment: @KuldeepRaj so you are not able to fetch user data from facebook? if you want to fetch data then that link is going to work out for you. After you fetch data use shared preferences to save data.